# What has happened to react.addons.batchedUpdates?

Tags: reactjs, flux

We are using the batchedUpdates addon to prevent issues with cascading updates with fluxxor - as per this page:

http://fluxxor.com/guides/react.html#batched-updates

However requiring addons with require react/addons and then using them with e.g. react.addons.batchedUpdates is depreciated. Now the addons are separate npm modules. As per this page:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/addons.html

But there is no mention of batchedUpdates - and there is no npm module react-addons-batched-updates.

Does this mean that this addon is no longer supported/offered?

Comment: This appears to be the answer: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html (not yet tested).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same answer, so just to complement Justin's answer, here's the exported functionality

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/35962a00084382b49d1f9e3bd36612925f360e5b/src/renderers/dom/ReactDOM.js#L40

And here's the warning that tells you where do find the new one:
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/401e6f10587b09d4e725763984957cf309dfdc30/src/addons/ReactWithAddons.js#L43